# Python: should Data Scaling be done before Sampling in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scaling, sampling, smote

When should I do data scaling and Sampling (since my data is imbalanced)?
Should I do data scaling first then Sampling?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to standardize/scale your independent values after sampling/splitting.

If you're into the Python programming language, `scikit-learn.org` has a few examples that might address your issue a little better.  [Here's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_scaling_importance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-scaling-importance-py) an example solution that deals with the importance of feature scaling.

[Here's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_nca_classification.html) another one that includes stratified sampling.